# How to reduce repeated code with different variable names (python)

Tags: python

```
class Budget:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wants_perc = 0
        self.wants_amt = 0
        self.wants_left = 0
        self.needs_perc = 0
        self.needs_amt = 0
        self.needs_left = 0
        self.food_perc = 0 
        self.food_amt = 0
        self.food_left = 0
        while True:
            try:
                self.monthly_income = float(input("Enter your monthly income after taxes: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid Input : Please enter a number")
                continue
            

        while True:
            print("Enter desired percentage of income spent for each category (do not include %): ")
            try:
                self.wants_perc = float(input("Wants: "))
                self.needs_perc = float(input("Needs: "))
                self.food_perc = float(input("Food: "))
                if self.wants_perc + self.needs_perc + self.food_perc not in range(95, 105):
                    print("Invalid Input : Must add to 100%")
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid Input : Please enter a number")
                continue

    def deposit(self):
        dep_loc = input("Where would you like to deposit? ")
        while True:
            try:
                if dep_loc.lower() == "wants":
                    self.wdep_amt = float(input("Deposit amount: "))
                    self.wants()
                    break
                elif dep_loc.lower() == "needs":
                    self.ndep_amt = float(input("Deposit amount: "))
                    self.needs()
                    break
                elif dep_loc.lower() == "food":
                    self.fdep_amt = float(input("Deposit amount: "))
                    self.food()
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid Input")
                    break
                    
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid Input : Please enter a number")
                continue
    
    def wants(self):
        self.wants_max = (self.wants_perc / 100) * self.monthly_income 
        self.wants_amt += self.wdep_amt
        self.wants_left = self.wants_max - self.wants_amt
        print(f"Amount spent on wants: ${self.wants_amt} \nAmount left to spend: ${round(self.wants_left,2)}")

    def needs(self):
        self.needs_max = (self.needs_perc / 100) * self.monthly_income 
        self.needs_amt += self.ndep_amt
        self.needs_left = self.needs_max - self.needs_amt
        print(f"Amount spent on needs: ${self.needs_amt} \nAmount left to spend: ${round(self.needs_left,2)}")

    def food(self):
        self.food_max = (self.food_perc / 100) * self.monthly_income 
        self.food_amt += self.fdep_amt
        self.food_left = self.food_max - self.food_amt
        print(f"Amount spent on food: ${self.food_amt} \nAmount left to spend: ${round(self.food_left,2)}")

wyatt = Budget()
while True:
    wyatt.deposit()
```

I know this is a very general question, but is it possible to reduce the amount of repeated code I use? I feel like there has to be a way to use one general variable in a loop for each of the categories. My three functions that use the food, wants, and needs variables are all the exact same besides the names. I thought of getting user input and adding it to a list and indexing that list to get each category, but I couldn't fully figure it out. This may be too broad for stack overflow and if it is I apologize. Thanks!

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no mechanism for reducing the amount of code - if there was, it would already be part of the language.  Making a dictionary instead of member variables doesn't really help, because all it will do is replace your 9 member variables with 9 dictionary items.

However, there is an opportunity for factoring out repeated operations.  Your instinct is correct that repeated blocks of code are a sign of poor design.  I would suggest you start with a class structure something like this:

```
class BudgetItem:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.perc = 0
        self.amt = 0
        self.left = 0
        
    def get_perc(self):
        self.perc = float(input(f"{self.name}: "))
        
class Budget:
    def __init__(self, monthly_income):
        self.monthly_income = monthly_income
        self.wants = BudgetItem("Wants")
        self.needs = BudgetItem("Needs")
        self.food = BudgetItem("Food")
        self.all_items = (self.wants, self.needs, self.food)
        
    def gather_percentages(self):
        print("Enter desired percentage of income"
              " spent for each category (do not include %): ")
        for b in self.all_items:
            b.get_perc()
        if 95.0 <= sum(b.perc for b in self.all_items) <= 105.0:
            print("Precentages must sum to 100")
        
# etc.
```

Create a separate class to represent a budget category, since the logic for each is identical.  Add methods to the little class to capture that logic.  Now re-write your main class in terms of those three individual items.  I won't take the time to refactor your whole program, but I hope you get the idea.  You should end up with a much shorter program and no significant repeated logic.

One other thing: I think that putting an "input" statement in a class constructor is a terrible idea.  Constructors should not contain complicated loops or extended logic.  I would put it outside the class and pass the data into the class as arguments, or as method calls.

Comment: ok thank you for the advice! I did this as a way to start learning oop in python and this is a big help. Seeing what I could have done better is huge when learning. Thanks much